# How to create new column based in other column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to create new column containing part_of_the_day when the category of application is more used (max duration between the same category) for example the calendar is used 2 times: the afternoon and the night by comparing the duration, I try to take the afternoon one. how can i do this .

```
UserId  Date        category       part_of_day  Frequency   duration_max
1      2020-09-10   System tool     evening       1          3.436
1      2020-09-11   Calendar        afternoon     5          5.313
1      2020-09-11   Calendar        night         3          2.760
1      2020-09-11   Clock           night         2          0.418
1      2020-09-11   Communication  afternoon      35         59.936
```

I want this result :

```
   UserId   Date        category       part_of_day  Frequency   duration_max
1      2020-09-10   System tool      evening            1            3.436
1      2020-09-11   Calendar         afternoon          5            5.313
1      2020-09-11   Clock            night              2            0.418
1      2020-09-11   Communication    afternoon         35            59.936
```

`

I found similar problems on the forum but I couldn't modify the code to work with my data.

Comment: Please do not post image of the data. Also please share the expected output. Couldnt clearly understand your need here.

Comment: Also give us the expected output.

Comment: Can you explain why solution from dupe not working for you?